# update value on button on:click event vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button

I am trying to update each temperature and city's names on my website, to do this i am using a function that works on button click , temperature updating works fine but my city's names are updating when i am selecting cities on the dropdown list selection, but i dont want that, i want to update it after the onclick on button.

There is the html template :

```
<template>
  <div class=location>
  <select  id="select" v-model="city">
     <option value="" selected disabled>Choisissez</option>
     <option v-for="city in cities" :value="city" :key="city.id">{{city.name}}</option>
     <button @click="refreshCityTemperature"  type="button"> Search </button>
  </select>
  </div class=location>
  <div class="meteo">
        <h1 id="MeteoActuelle"> Météo actuelle à {{city.name}} </h1>
        <p> Temperature : {{ temp }} °c </p>
  </div class="meteo">      
</template>

the js code : 

export default {
  name: 'Meteo',
  data() { 
    return {
      temp: Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 10) ) + 10,
      today: moment().format('Do MMMM  YYYY'),
      city: {},
      cities: [
            {
                id: "PAR", name: "Paris"
            },
            {
                id: "MAR", name: "Marseille"
            },
            {
                id: "LYO", name: "Lyon"
            }            
      ]  
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.city = this.cities[0];
  },
  methods: {
      refreshCityTemperature(){
            this.cities = city.name;
            this.temp=Math.floor(Math.random() * (30 - 10) ) + 10;
    }
  }
}
```

do you have any idea how to do it ? i am really new on vue js

Comment: you're overriding the cities array by `city.name` which is of type string, why are you doing that?

Comment: because i want to display the name of the city selected on my dropdown list when i click on the button , i thought it was a good idea, obviously it is not, what's the moove ? @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: You want the city and temperature to be updated only when you click the button ? @kehalS

Comment: Yeah exactly ! @BSYoann

Comment: Try out `this.cities = [this.city];`

Comment: Then your code looks good, just the button element in your template shouldn't be in the select, and you can remove 'this.cities = city.name;' in refreshCityTemperature.
You can take a look at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-moon-xsr98?file=/src/App.vue). I did it to test your code

Comment: I tried it, remove me my cities on my dropdown list and i can choose only Paris wich is my first element @BoussadjraBrahim

Comment: But it still update the city when selected on the drop down list and not on the button ? i am missing something ? @BSYoann

Comment: You're right, i suggest you then to add a temporary variable that take the value of this.city when you press the button. And display this new variable instead of this.city which is attached to the selected value. (I updated the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-moon-xsr98?file=/src/App.vue) if you want)

Comment: It worked amazing thank you !! so if i understand the thing is you create a temporary variable to avoid overriding of city.name , right ? @BSYoann

Comment: @kehalS your 'city' has a 2 way binding because of v-model="city". So when you select a new city, the value is automatically put in your 'city' variable. It's the v-model magic.
There are certainly other way to achieve your needs. But the first way i'm thinking is having another variable 'displayedCity' that you affect with the 'city' value when the user click the button (and then display this 'displayedCity').